# firebase facebook login / sign-up not working for some users

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I want to implement facebook login through firebase with angularFire (for angularJS)
It is working fine for some users - but for others the following happens:

1. The get redirected to facebook and confirm they want to log or sign
   in to my app
2. They get redirected back to my page
3. My angularfire onAuthState is triggered - but no firebase user is there

Thing is: I can't replicate it because on my devices it works fine.

Does anybody have an idea what might be the issue?

It did work in Chrome (61, desktop and 62 mobile) and Safari (v. unknown). But not for another Safari client nor for a mobile Safari.

I gather this from the fact that it logs 'no firebase user' for them, i.e. ends up in the else branch of the first if

This is my code it is situated in an angularJS service available to all controllers:

```
 // any time auth state changes, add the user data to scope
self.auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function (firebaseUser) {
    self.firebaseUser = firebaseUser;

    // get the token from the firebase User Object
    // Note that getToken() is deprecated and for me it did not work as desired
    // use getIdToken() instead
    if (self.firebaseUser) {
        firebaseUser.getIdToken().then(function (idToken) {

          // firebase thinks facebook e-mails are unverified by default, for me they are fine
            if (!firebaseUser.emailVerified && !(firebaseUser.providerData[0].providerId === 'facebook.com')) {
                $location.path('/pleaseVerify');
            } else {
                self.idToken = idToken;
                self.gapiToken = {
                    access_token: self.idToken.toString()
                };
            }
        });
        $location.path('/landing');
    } else {
        $log.log("no firebase user");
        //$location.path('/landing');
    }

    // TODO: redirect User to where he was last?
});
```

This is the code that takes all users to facebook and back (some with a firebase user, some without)

```
/**
 * SignIn using social Auth provider
 * @param googleorfacebook a string value whether we want to sign in with google or facebook
 * can be either "google" or "facebook"
 */
self.socialAuth = function (googleorfacebook) {
    self.auth.$signInWithRedirect(googleorfacebook).then(function () {
        // Never called because of page redirect
        // Instead, use $onAuthStateChanged() to detect successful authentication
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
    });
};
```

Comment: Are you using Safari in private browsing mode? If so, redirect/popup operations do not work in that mode.

Comment: the issue persists outside of private mode

Comment: That is strange. Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No errors. but it does log "no firebase user". I.e. On onAuthStateChanged is triggered, but there is no firebaseUser - and only for some users.

Comment: @SLLegendre did you find a solution for this? Facing the same issue